# Use of clear in java.lang.ref.Reference class

Tags: java, garbage-collection, phantom-reference

```
ReferenceQueue q = new ReferenceQueue();
Reference r = q.remove();
r.clear();
```

I see that the java doc says that the `clear` method clears this reference object. I don't understand the meaning of this. Does this `clear` from the memory and thus in other words the object has been garbage collected?

Comment: I deleted my answer because after seeing your comment on it, I'm pretty sure I didn't explain what I wanted to properly. I'll try doing that in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

`clear()` simply sets the internal reference to `null`. Since references are automatically cleared when being enqueued by the garbage collector (with the exception of phantom references, but this oddity can be ignored, it will be eliminated in Java 9), there is usually no need to call `clear()` on a reference received via `ReferenceQueue.remove()`.

In principle, there is the possibility to enqueue references manually via `enqueue()` without clearing them, but there is little sense in that, as the primary purpose of the reference queue is to learn about references being enqueued by the garbage collector which *will* be cleared.

When you call `clear()` on a `Reference` object that has not been enqueued yet, it may allow the referent to get collected without enqueuing the `Reference` object. On the other hand, when you don’t need the `Reference` object anymore, you can let the JVM collect it like an ordinary object, together with the referent if there are no other references left, as in that case, it won’t get enqueued as well, making `clear()` unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.Reference` is a base class for few special references which are treated in special way by garbage collection.

Under certain circumstances garbage collector may push reference object in it's reference queue (reference may be queued only once in a lifetime).

`clear()` method can be used to suppress special handling (and thus additional work for garbage collector). If reference object is already in queue it doesn't make sense to clear it, it is already cleared by garbage collector.

[This project](https://github.com/aragozin/example-finalization) on github has an implementation of resource management using `PhantomReference`s made for educational purpose. `clear()` is used if resource is disposed explicitly to avoid extra work for GC in that case.